Count of workorders without line items
I'm trying to get a count of workorders that have not been billed (ie do not have any line items associated with the workorder)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workorders (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        work_date date
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workorder_line_items (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        workorder_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES workorders (id) on UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        product_id int  NOT NULL REFERENCES products (id) on UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        units numeric(10,2) NOT NULL
);

I feel like im getting close here, but can't quite get there.
select count(*) from workorders 
left join workorder_line_items on workorder_line_items.workorder_id = workorders.id
where count(workorder_line_items) = 0


That doesn't work, because the LEFT JOIN will not produce any records that aren't in both tables.  You might try WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT UNIQUE id FROM workorder_line_items).

select count(*) 
from workorders 
     left join 
     workorder_line_items 
     on workorder_line_items.workorder_id = workorders.id
where workorder_line_items.workorder_id is null

When using a LEFT JOIN, for rows in the LEFT table but not in the RIGHT table (those you are seeking to count), the columns referenced from the RIGHT table (in SELECT or WHERE clauses) return NULL. All you need to do is to test for that.
This would also work, and the intention is a bit more obvious (at least to me):
select count(*) 
from workorders wo
where not exists 
    (select * 
     from workorder_line_items woli
     where woli.workorder_id=wo.id)

I have just noticed @Tim_Robert's comment, that would also work.
